# Shopware - Extjs - How to get value of the table element?

Tags: extjs, shopware

For some time I have a problem with my Shopware plugin. I extended article listWindow, added a column with checkbox. When customer clicks on checkbox I need to get article number that is in another column.

The way I first did it seems unreliable because it depends on position of a columns that can change.

```
//{block name="backend/article_list/view/main/grid"}
//{$smarty.block.parent}
//{namespace name=backend/article_list/main}
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.ArticleList.view.main.etsy_attribute.Grid', {

    override: 'Shopware.apps.ArticleList.view.main.Grid',

    ...

    getToolbar: function () {
        var me = this, buttons;

        buttons = me.callParent();
        me.equaliseEtsyBtn = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
            text: 'Etsy equalise',
            iconCls: 'sprite-drive-upload',
            onClick: function () {
                var i,
                recPerPage = me.items.items[0].all.elements,

                for (i = 0; i < recPerPage.length; i++) {
                    var productNumber = recPerPage[i].children[2].innerText;
                if( recPerPage[i].children[numOfChildren].children[0].children[0].checked === true) {
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: '{url controller="someController" action="someAction"}',
                            params: Object.assign({
                                productNumber: productNumber
                            }),
                            success: function (res) {
                                //var parsed = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                            },
                            failure: function () {

                            }
                        });
                    } else {

                        });

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        buttons.add(me.equaliseEtsyBtn);

        return buttons;
    },

})
```

What is bad here is this:

```
recPerPage[i].children[numOfChildren].children[0].children[0].checked === true
```

And similar lines. How to get value I need in some smarter and more accurate way?

Alse tried with .down and .up

Please give me some direction!

Comment: Hi, in case you are overriding ext grid panel, better solution would be to set a grid reference on it. Then you can use that reference and access it's store where you have all records available. I would iterate over store's records and than ask if any of checkboxes are checked. This would make you independent of any dom changes..

Comment: Aha, I did not know  that. Thanks! I will try that tomorrow and let you know if i succeed.